# Расположение элементов в TabHost

Tags: android, xml

Пытаюсь сделать прозрачный `TabWidget` наконец то получилось, но вот все элементы которые находятся в данном layout опускаются до конца экрана, которые находятся за `TabWidget`, что б было понятней что у меня сейчас происходит, добавляю картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За `TabWidget` находятся элементы. Я пытался `margin` и `padding` исправить положение, но безуспешно

Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
           >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#D92a5094"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:showDividers="none" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Решил проблему вот так:**

```
View listFooter = new View(this);
        listFooter.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 80));
        list.addFooterView(listFooter);
```

Comment: Если вы сами нашли решение, оформите его, как ответ, а не предлагайте решение в самом вопросе. Такие тут правила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вашу роблему должно решить простая замена `FrameLayout` на `LinearLayout`. Дело в том, что фреймлэйаут накладывает свой слой поверх других элементов. Линейный лэйаут(как, впрочем и все другие, кроме фрэйма) учитывает присутствие других элементов и не "претендует" на их место.